# java.lang.NumberFormatException:

Tags: java, selenium, appium

```
Integer value = Rs 5000
```

reading that integer value and split it by space so that I can get only the integer value. But when i am executing the script it shows " 5000".Why is it so.

Log error:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5000
>       at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)

```
int claimAmount= Integer.parseInt(getText(MyClaimsObject.estClaimAmount).split( " ")[1]);
System.out.println(claimAmount);
```

Comment: I've just tried it with the hard-coded value and it's working fine for me.  Double-check that `getText` is returning exactly what you think it is.

Comment: please add the  `getText(...)` method you are using

Comment: quote the "Rs 5000" string

Answer (score 0):

Speculation: there is leading or trailing white space. Easiest solution (that I see), use a regular expression to strip non-digits from your input. Like,

```
String claimStr = getText(MyClaimsObject.estClaimAmount).replaceAll("\\D+", "");
int claimAmount = Integer.parseInt(claimStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Potentially you have something trailing the `5000` value e.g. unprintable UTF characters. The exception text should be `For input string: "5000"`, you are missing the closing `"` character.

Ensure that you are cleaning up the user input e.g. by disallowing non-numeric characters in the input.